# Creating a PowerShell Function to calculate average rates

Tags: powershell, function, loops, csv

I'm working on a project, and I'm stumped, so I'm turning to you guys for a little help.

What I need to do is Create a function with the required filename parameter, which I have done already, and then This function will calculate and print out the average residential rate for all entries in the file. The following function needs to do the following task:

```
1. Import the CSV file
2. Create a loop to read and add the rates
3. calculate the average of the rates
4. write the output to the console
```

My current function and script is :

```
function Get-Rates {
param (
    #This Paramater is mandatory
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[string] $Filepath
)

#This script will import the Filepath of a csv file, select residential_rate and send it to variable RR

Import-Csv -Path $Filepath | Select-Object residential_rate -OutVariable RR 

#Here i want it to loop and calcuate the average reseidential_rate for all entries in the csv  file 

for ($RR = 0; $RR -lt $array.Count; $RR++) {
<# Action that will repeat until the condition is met #>
}
```

I'm trying to create the loop, but I'm unsure if it should be a for loop, do loop, or foreach.

Comment: Have a look at ```Measure-Object``` - this will calculate the average of a property for you. You'd do something like ```$data = Import-Csv -Path $fliename; $data | measure-object -Property "residential_rate" -Average | select-object -ExpandProperty "Average"```. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7.3 for details.

Comment: Where is variable `$array` defined in your function?